# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'REACT_APP_SC_ATTR')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styled-components

I have a react project I'm trying to get to work with next js

I'm getting the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'REACT_APP_SC_ATTR')
```

Error relates to code:

```
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={createTheme(theme)}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={createTheme(theme)}>
          <AuthProvider>{Component}</AuthProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
```

If I remove this code the error goes away.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant code trying to access a `REACT_APP_SC_ATTR` value? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Is there a code stacktrace accompanying the error that provides a link right to, or close to it, the line of code causing the issue?

Comment: It's accessed by the npm module styled-components

Comment: Callstack:

Call Stack
eval
node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js (1:1130)
Module../node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js
file:///Users/greg/Documents/development/lyg/liftyourgame/.next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js (2495:1)
Module.options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (606:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/greg/Documents/development/lyg/liftyourgame/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (275:21)